# Surface Area Relative to Element Distribution

Tags: gravity, geophysics, non-equilibrium, stellar-evolution

We tend to find heavier elements like iron and others toward the center of celestial bodies.  Lighter elements like carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen are almost always towards the surface.  That makes sense because heavier elements have a greater gravitational effect and would naturally want to move toward the center.

Now think about the chaos that ensued during initial formation of the celestial body.  Heavier elements could get jumbled in with lighter elements throughout the depths.  Even to this day, we have lighter elements being pushed to the surface through volcanic gases and ocean fissures.

**Question**: If elements were not always arranged from heaviest to lightest during creation, would this in anyway introduce volatility in the overall surface area of the celestial body?  Imagine the worst case scenario that would be utterly unimaginable: gold and iron wrapped around the surface with oxygen and hydrogen trapped deep within the depths.  Would the overall surface area be any different over time as heavier elements pushed their way in and lighter elements rise to the surface?

Intuitively, I would say it would change over time, but to what degree and at what rate of change depends on how elements were initially distributed.

Comment: It would help if you made clear what you mean by "celestial body." Planets? asteroids? comets? stars?

Comment: Put it this way, at any scale, would the distribution have a profound impact on the surface area over time?  Planets are just easier to conceptualize for this question.

Comment: Soo...your question is on the nucleosynthesis in planets, and no in stars?

Comment: I am more interested in the effects of gravity over a varying distribution of "existing elements" that comprise masses like planets and stars.  The process of creating new atomic nuclei from existing nucleons is really beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is more easy to conceptualize in stars than in planets, so this answer is going to reflect that.

Stars stay the size they are due to hydrostatic equilibrium: the force due to gravity is matched by the pressure gradient,
$$
\frac{dP}{dr} = -\frac{Gm\rho}{r^2}
$$

If we consider a parcel of matter somewhere in your hypothetical star at a position $r$ and of thickness $dr$, i.e.,

[image: crude star]

we have that $P(r+dr)>P(r)$, thus the force due to pressure on this parcel is
$$
F_P(r) = P(r)dS - P(r+dr)dS < 0
$$
Since $F_g(r)<0$, then your star necessarily cannot support itself and will be begin to fall inwards. That is to say, the surface area would (likely rapidly) decrease until the inner region of the star generated pressure enough to balance the outer regions of the star.

Comment: Hydrostatic equilibrium can only be achieved when the body is at rest or each part has a constant flow velocity.  Only when elements have been distributed by mass (heaviest in the core and lightest at the surface) can this be achieved.  Otherwise, gravity is still forcing heavier elements down and lighter elements to the surface.  This response doesn't seem to address the surface area changes over time as gravity pulls heavier elements inward and lighter elements expand as their pressure drops while rising to the surface.

Comment: Actually, I state quite clearly that stars balance because of HSE, but then go on to **not** consider it and show why one should **not** expect the star to remain its size and would collapse (i.e., the surface area would **decrease** because it is falling *inwards*). Perhaps I expected more "in between the lines" reading, but I amended my answer to reflect your desires.

Comment: Think of the hypothetical scenario in my question.  The inner lighter elements become closer and closer together at increasing depths providing an increasing counter pressure.  So P(r) > P(r + dr) in this scenario.  Sure if the interior had a lower pressure, the higher pressure would over come it, shrinking the overall size until it reached equilibrium.  However, that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Your question simply asks what happens to the surface area due to inverting the order of elements found in a star. I gave the answer: it decreases. What more are you looking for?

Comment: The hypothetical scenario tried to describe a situation where the lighter interior elements become more pressurized (packed closer together at deeper depths) and would have greater pressure to resist that of higher depths.  Thus no collapse due to element distribution.  The body's size would either expand or stay the same, but would not shrink.  Look at Jupiter or super earth-like planets.  Hydrogen gas many miles in is pressurized so much it starts behaving like a fluid & conducting electricity.  You seem to imply lighter elements cannot be pressurized enough to hold up heavier elements.

Comment: Pressure due to density profile, which comes from the elemental make up. If your more-dense elements are further out, then their pressure will be greater than the pressure of the less-dense inner region. Perhaps it would be in your interest to review the [Rayleigh-Taylor instability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh–Taylor_instability).

Comment: Either way the volume never changes.  The potential energy lowers as denser parcels displace downward with an equal volume of lighter parcels displaced upwards.  So why would the surface area shrink?  After redistribution, the surface area would either be the same or potentially larger.  The lighter parcels now at the surface are no longer kept under extreme pressure and can spread out.